# Constraint only 3 of the same value pairs allowed

Tags: sql, mariadb, constraints

I want to create a constraint, that ensures that max 3 times of a combination is inserted into the table.

I tried like this:

```
CREATE or replace TABLE nobelpreis (
  category VARCHAR(255),
  year Integer,
  pnr Integer,
  CONSTRAINT max_tripple CHECK count(category , year )<3
);
```

Example:

```
INSERT INTO nobelpreis VALUES("Physics", 2007, 121);
INSERT INTO nobelpreis VALUES("Physics", 2007, 122);
INSERT INTO nobelpreis VALUES("Physics", 2007, 123);
INSERT INTO nobelpreis VALUES("Physics", 2007, 124); // error ("Physics", 2007) exists already 3 times
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Most likely this will need to be done via a trigger, but the product you are using will determine how this is pulled off.

Comment: I am using mariadb and this is just for studying. So no triggers allowed :/